# Is there an enzyme that functions without being associated with a complex?

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, protein-binding, enzyme-kinetics, protein-interaction

I'm looking for an enzyme that does not function as part of a complex in its active state. Preferably it also is not part of a kinase or other kind of activating cascade as well though I would appreciate any and all names that are not part of a complex in its active state. Also would be better if it does not require post translational modifications. Of course, pre translational modifications/ interactions at rna or dna level are all good.
In **eukaryotic genome** but bonus points for *human genome*!
Thanks!!

Comment: Ribozymes may answer your conundrum here.

Comment: Ribozymes are made of 2 subunits though. I'm basically wondering if there is a protein with no quaternary structure and maybe even those little things I mentioned above.

Comment: This seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm not really sure how else to phrase unfortunately. But that's a good thing to learn about! Feel free to edit or advise and I'll comply!

Comment: I can't really suggest an edit because I have no idea what problem you are trying to solve, and that's kind of the problem with XY questions. What is your *goal*?

Comment: Please provide context (why do you want to know this?) and evidence of your own research. Please restrict yourself to asking a question. We have our own scoring system here and it does not involve posters awarding bonus points. Nor is this necessary as you’ll find it more difficult to find proteins present in other eukaryotes and not man than those also present in man.

Comment: I don't really get what David is saying but Bryan, I'm mostly trying to figure this out just cause I can't think of any. Goal is to just name an enzyme which doesn't have a quaternary structure in active form and preferable has no cofactors attached or required and post translational modification.

Answer (score 3):

Acetylcholinesterase.

Chosen because the esterase seems like a low energy reaction so it wouldn't need energetic co-factors.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylcholinesterase

Not sure if I should do a new answer or not.

Comment: Yeah. The Zn is a cofactor so technically doesn't add to the quaternary structure. I'll keep the question open in case someone identifies a completely isolated enzyme.

Comment: @SarthakGarg , i have changed my answer.